# Create Contact Group with Members in O365 Exchange using EWS

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365

I would like to create a contact group with members in a public folder on Office 365 Exchange using a Powershell Script that uses EWS.

I already achieved to:

- Create contacts in a public folder on Office 365 Exchange (New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact)
- Create contact groups in a public folder on Office 365 Exchange (New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ContactGroup)

...but what I tried in several ways but could not get working is to put the contact in the contact group :-)

Anyone who can help me with this?

Thank you a lot!
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

based on EWS API documentation,

[`ContactGroup` has a property named `Members`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contactgroup.members.aspx),

you should be able to add the contact to it by using [`AddPersonalContact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee356352.aspx).

Other methods to fill the `ContactGroup` is listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.groupmembercollection_members.aspx)

if `$contactgroup` contains an instance of `ContactGroup`, then add add contact to it using :

```
$contactgroup.Members.AddPersonalContact(...)
```